# Cannot submit app to iTunes, binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 ERROR

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I've been trying to submit my archive for quite some time now, people seem to have this problem alot, and I of course have to be the one with the same problem but in need of a different solution.
Upon submitting an error is thrown at me (see screenshot)
[image: ERROR]

Basically what it says is that I need a launchimage for iPhone 5 4" display. Of course I added it but it doesn't seem to be right anyway. I added it to the LaunchImage catalog under "Images.xcassets", and also three images using special names that was supposed to work (all images is the right sizes). See below screenshot how it's arranged.
[image: LaunchImages]

So, from what I managed to gather through looking at how others have fixed this issue, this should do it. The threads I stumbled upon all use this very xcode-specific lingo (never sat behind a mac until two weeks ago, so can't say I'm well versed here) and no screenshots, so hopefully I just misunderstood where to put what.

tl;dr
Submitting app, won't accept my launchimages

***EDIT***
Answer submitted, but can't flag it as such in two days.

Comment: just a advise, add your solution in a new answer instead in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't paying enough attention, the correct filename for "Default-568@2x" should be "Default-568h@2x". Notice the 'h'. How silly. Now submitting was successful!